# Casting from one pointer to pointer type to another in Golang error

Tags: pointers, go

Can anyone tell my why this wouldn't compile?

```
package main

type myint int
func set(a **myint) {
    i := myint(5)
    *a = &i 
}

func main() {
    var k *int
    set( (**myint)(&k) ) // cannot convert &k (type **int) to type **myint
    print( *k )
}
```

My reasoning so far is this. All types in Golang are different, but it allows to convert from one type to another with C-like cast syntax as long as underlying types are identical. In my example, converting 'int' to 'myint' is not a problem. '*int' to '*myint' isn't either. It's when you have pointer to pointer problems arise. I've been stuck on this for the second day now. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's my analysis.

`(**myint)(&k)` -- cannot convert `&k` (`type **int`) to `type **myint`:

`type **int` and `type **myint` are unnamed pointer types and their pointer base types, `type *int` and `type *myint`, don't have identical underlying types.

If T (`*int` or `*myint`) is a pointer type literal, the corresponding underlying type is T itself.

`(*myint)(k)` -- can convert `k` (`type *int`) to `type *myint`:

`type *int` and `type *myint` are unnamed pointer types and their pointer base types, `type int` and `type myint` (`type myint int`), have identical underlying types.

If T (`int`) is a predeclared type, the corresponding underlying type is T itself. If T (`myint`) is neither a predeclared type or nor a type literal, T's underlying type is the underlying type of the type to which T refers in its type declaration (`type myint int`).

`(myint)(*k)` -- can convert `*k` (`type int`) to `type myint`:

`type int` and `type myint` have identical underlying types.

If T (`int`) is a predeclared type, the corresponding underlying type is T itself. If T (`myint`) is neither a predeclared type or nor a type literal, T's underlying type is the underlying type of the type to which T refers in its type declaration (`type myint int`).

Here's the underlying type example from the Types section revised to use integers and int pointers.

```
type T1 int
type T2 T1
type T3 *T1
type T4 T3
```

The underlying type of `int`, `T1`, and `T2` is `int`. The underlying type of `*T1`, `T3`, and `T4` is `*T1`.

References:

[The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html)

[Conversions](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Conversions)

[Types](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Types)

[Properties of types and values](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Properties_of_types_and_values)

[Type declarations](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Type_declarations)

[Predeclared identifiers](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Predeclared_identifiers)

[Pointer Type](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Pointer_types)

Comment: Thank you. Third line is the answer that I was looking for.

Comment: I think you could add also this link: 
http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity

Two named types are identical if their type names originate in the same TypeSpec.  so  myint != int and *myint != *int

Comment: @DanielSperry Your statement about the pointers seems to be wrong, because the answer with the examples shows how to cast from `*int` to `*myint` and the other way round from `*myint` to `*int`. It is only necessary to be a bit more explicit in double references.

Answer (score 15):

Here are two functionally equivalent working versions of your program.

```
package main

type mypint *int

func set(a *mypint) {
    i := int(5)
    *a = &i
}

func main() {
    var k *int
    set((*mypint)(&k))
    print(*k)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/l_b9LBElie

```
package main

type myint int

func set(a *myint) *myint {
    i := myint(5)
    a = &i
    return a
}

func main() {
    var k *int
    k = (*int)(set((*myint)(k)))
    print(*k)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/hyaPFUNlp8