# Convert string to *uint64 in golang

Tags: string, pointers, go, uint64

Assume there is a string holding the address of an `uint64` type variable, can we parse this address back to an `*uint64`?

For example:

```
i := uint64(23473824)
ip := &i
str := fmt.Sprintf("%v", ip)

u, _ := strconv.ParseUint(str, 0, 64)
```

`u` is `uint64`. How to get pointer out of this value?

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/1KXFQcozRk

Comment: I don't understand golang, but is this page helpful (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367961/casting-from-one-pointer-to-pointer-type-to-another-in-golang-error)? It deals with casting pointers.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately they are not related.

Comment: _but why would you need to do this?_

Comment: @Rambatino that's a great question, but let's just say I was on the dark side once.

Answer (score 18):

It is as simple as:

```
number, err := strconv.ParseUint(string("90"), 10, 64)
```

then do some error checking, hope it helps.

Comment: this doesn't work if `uint` is a 32-bit type, so it won't work in 32-bit builds

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with

```
 ip = (*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(u)))
```

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/Ei8-WbUp15)

Albeit I don't know what guarantees Go gives you about the validity of such a pointer, nor can I think of any use case where this code should be used..

Answer (score 4):

Based on [nos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28967798/450989).

Although it is technically possible there are reasons not to trust the code you wrote. Garbage collection will use the memory you point to (with string).

Take a look at result of the following code.

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func produce() string {
    i := uint64(23473824)
    ip := &i
    str := fmt.Sprintf("%v", ip)
    fmt.Println(i, ip, str)
    return str
}

func main() {
    str := produce()

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
         x := make([]int, 1024*1024)
         x[0] = i
    }        

    u, _ := strconv.ParseUint(str, 0, 64) 

    ip := (*uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(u)))
    fmt.Println(ip,*ip, reflect.TypeOf(u)) // u is uint64, how to get pointer out of this value?
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/85XOhsMTf3